# Laravel: Ajax - how "force" download pdf from storage directory

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Yes ... I know the subject may seem duplicitous, but I have used several alternatives found in stackoverflow, but practically all attempts have failed.

**Scenario**

- Laravel Framework 5.7.11 (I cannot upgrade to version 5.8 at this time).
- league/flysystem v1.0.51 (latest update).

**Requirement**

- Double click in 'Datatables' row and download pdf file.

**Router**

```
Route::get('/download/{id?}', 'Mensagem\DocumentoController@download')->name('Documento.download');
```

**Controller**

```
    public function download()
    {
       return response()->download(storage_path('app/' . 'storage_app_file.pdf'));
    }
```

**jQuery/Ajax**

```
/* DOUBLE CLICK ROW */
$datatable.find("tbody").on("dblclick", "tr", function() {
  let data = table.row(this).data();

  $.ajax({
    url: '{{route("Documento.download")}}',
    type: "get",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,

    beforeSend: function() {
      console.log("double click beforeSend...");
    },

    success: function() {
      console.log("DOUBLE CLICK ROW: success...");
    }
  });
});
```

**Result (no download file and 'binany content' as a result)**
[image]

[image]

### *Updated 209-04-04 15:23

#### Possible solution...

For some reason simply by using...

```
{{--window.open = '{{route("Documento.download")}}';--}}
```

... even changing the name of the file in the controller, always downloading the same file before ...

I decided to make a Response macro:

```
        \Response::macro('attachment', function ($content) {

            $rand = mt_rand(11111, 99999);

            $filename = 'download-' . "{$rand}" . '.pdf';

            $headers = [
                'Content-type'        => 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $filename .
                    '"',
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'Binary"',
            ];

            return \Response::make($content, 200, $headers);

        });
```

... and in controller:

```
$file = \Storage::disk('local')->get( $name );
return response()->attachment( $file );
```

... in 'double click'...

```
                let myWindow = window.open('{{route("Documento.download")}}', '_blank', 'location=yes,height=400,width=300,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');

                setTimeout(() => myWindow.close(), 3000);
```

Comment: You can't download files via AJAX, no matter what server tricks you play. The data ends up in a JavaScript variable in your page instead of in a file on the user's disk. Use a standard GET request. Maybe make it open in a separate window/tab using (window.open()) if you like

Answer (score 0):

Why ajax? I think the easiest way is:

```
$datatable.find("tbody").on("dblclick", "tr", function() {
  window.location = '{{route("Documento.download")}}';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ... yes ... I had tested it that way, but although it does not make sense ... "it seems" there is a bug, because if I download a file once .... and rename it , if it tries to execute again, it continues downloading the same file, however, I do not know this is an expected behavior, as if it were a cache.

Comment: Even forcing the controller to generate an error: ```return response()->download(storage_path('app/' . 'file-' . mt_rand() ));```